# LinQ related , filtering result from a Dictionary Object

Tags: c#, linq

**Answer solved in edit below**

I had this piece of code

```
Dictionary<Merchant, int> remaingCards = CardService.GetRemainingCardsNumber(int.MaxValue, 0).Result;
```

GetRemainingCardsNumber returns Merchants object with Id and Name property , and the matching card numbers as Int .

Now , let say I want to filter the dictionary based on the Name property inside the Merchant object . I did it like this :

```
cardmodel.MerchantRemainingCards = from Dictionary<Merchant, int> filterRemaining in cardserv.GetRemainingCardsNumber(int.MaxValue, 0).Result
                                                   where filterRemaining.Keys.FirstOrDefault().Name.Contains(merchantNameFilter)
                                                   select filterRemaining;
```

But obviously its not working because I'm not familiar with dictionary type .

**-- solved it here --**

```
        cardmodel.MerchantRemainingCards = cardserv.GetRemainingCardsNumber(int.MaxValue, 0).Result
                                           .Where(e => e.Key.Name.ToLower().Contains(merchantNameFilter.ToLower()))
                                           .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

Just cast it back to dictionary .

Comment: A good way to _become_ familiar with the dictionary type is to read the documentation: [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you suggest, your first bit of code does return a `Dictionary` then you should be able to do this:

```
from KeyValuePair<Merchant, int> card in cardserv.GetRemainingCardsNumber(int.MaxValue, 0).Result 
where card.Key.Name.Contains(merchantNameFilter)
select card;
```

Comment: cardmodel.MerchantRemainingCards itself is a dictionary , how do I convert the KeyValuePair back to dictionary ?

Comment: You don't.  but what you have about is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` which you can convert to a `Dictionary` using the `.ToDictionary()` method.

Answer (score 0):

possible alternative

```
var remaingCards = cardserv.GetRemainingCardsNumber(int.MaxValue, 0).Result.SelectMany(x => x.Keys).Where(x => x.Name.Contains(merchantNameFilter));
```